# Is there a way a website can identify me when connected to it via Orbot?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, security, orbot, vpn

When using Orbot and not coupled with Tor browser, but rather through Google Chrome or Firefox, can a website I visit de-anonymize me? Particularly know anything about my location, IP, service provider?

If so, how can I get [tails](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tails_(operating_system)) level security/privacy on my phone?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, google chrome and regular Firefox have unique fingerprints that can help to identify you. I personally think you're better off using something like NetGuard and just blocking all wifi access except tor and a few other essentials.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get location, IP, service provider through Java. Turn it off and you'll be fine.
However, it is highly recommend to use Tor Browser.
Use it with Java off for peace of mind.

Comment: How do you turn Java of on Tor browser (Android)?

Comment: Settings - - - > Security Settings

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if something/anything is leaking any kind of your data. The OrBot - or TransProxy in Linux/Unix - it's *just* a route diversion layer that works **only** if there's nothing else is leaking your data. In a simple example: a tool like `wget` or `fetch` or `curl-cli` will not leak anything by **itself**, but anything else that is running(and there's a lot of stuff on Android for OrBot - including a proprietary/closed-source OS kernel itself) that can avoid it